# get first n characters of a sting in javascript

Tags: javascript

This javascript code needs to print out:

```
c  
ce  
cef
```

```js
let str = 'cef'

for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  console.log(str.slice(0, i));
}
//prints, "", "c", "ce" instead of "c","ce","cef"
```

I tried few other things with `substr` for no avail. Any ideas? thx

Comment: Well the string from the `0`th character to the `0` th character is empty. Then from `0` to `1` is the single `"c"` and `0` to `2` is the `"ce"`. Your looking for `str.slice(0, i + 1)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start your loop at `1`, and end at `str.length`, because `slice` prints the characters up to but *not including* the second argument.

```js
let str = 'cef';

for (let i = 1; i <= str.length; i++) {
  console.log(str.slice(0, i));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of starting at 0, start at 1.

The index of 0 will start at the beginning of the string. You're initially asking for the first characters going from 0 to 0, which means you'll get back nothing.

Similarly, you'll need to increment your end value by one as well.

Comment: They won't get `"cef"` then.